# Data Validation from another Spreadsheet Range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a spreahsheet A on Googlesheet with a range, list of cities for example.
I have a spreadsheet B on Googlesheet where I'd like to use Data Validation validating from the other file.

**Goal**
The purpose is to 'hide' or make it less available, if I use protect/hide any download to Excel removes the protection and it's not really protected.

I thought I could use a custom function to set dataValidation and it works but if I add a city in spreadsheet A it's not reflected in the previous cells.

**Option 1**
*This works but the validation rule is not refreshed*

```
var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spread-a").getSheetByName("Data");
var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dataSheet.getRange('Cities').getValues()).build();
getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().setDataValidation(rule);
```

**Option 2**

*Custom function doesn't work*
*using it as Formula *=getList('Cities')**

```
function getList(name) {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dataSheet.getRange(name).getValues()).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Hello @IlanLevy, have you tried using a trigger for the first option? You might want to check this link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Cheers!

Comment: The first code snippet isn't complete. Please add a [mcve]. Regarding option 2, custom functions can't execute methods that require authorization.